# Remove Spikes from Periodic Data with MATLAB

Tags: matlab, outliers

I have some data which is time-stamped by a NMEA GPS string that I decode in order to obtain the single data point Year, Month, Day, etcetera.

The problem is is that in few occasions the GPS (probably due to some signal loss) goes boinks and it spits out very very wrong stuff. This generates spikes in the time-stamp data as you can see from the attached picture which plots the vector of Days as outputted by the GPS.

[image: Random spikes in timestamp]

As you can see, the GPS data are generally well behaved, and the days go between 1 and 30/31 each month before falling back to 1 at the next month. In certain moments though, the GPS spits out a random day.

I tried all the standard MATLAB functions for despiking (such as medfilt1 and findpeaks), but either they are not suited to the task, either I do not know how to set them up properly.

My other idea was to loop over differences between adjacent elements, but the vector is so big that the computer cannot really handle it.

Is there any vectorized way to go down such a road and detect those spikes?

Thanks so much!

Comment: could you upload your data?

Comment: can you try this? `d1=[diff(y) 0];`   `q=q=find(diff(abs(d1))==0);` `plot(1:10,[y(1:q(1)-1) y(q(1)+2) y(q(1)+2) y(q(1)+2:end)],'r')`. Where `y` are your data. let me know please.

Answer (score 0):

you need to filter your data using a simple low pass to get rid of the outliers:

```
windowSize = 5; 
b = (1/windowSize)*ones(1,windowSize);
a = 1;

FILTERED_DATA = filter(b,a,YOUR_DATA);
```

just play a bit with the windowSize until you get the smoothness you want.

Comment: Dear Noa, thanks for your quick answer! Maybe I'm doing something wrong, but filtering, besides smoothing spikes, also shifts the time series forward (i.e.: the change in day happens at different indexes than in the non filtered time series).

Comment: well filtering does induce a delay, you can filter other datasets as well to get a constant shift